# How to use Bitmap and canvas? to create my custom watermarks

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-bitmap

In my app I am trying to create watermarks on the image when either user captures it from camera or uploads from gallery. but the problem is that when I draw text on the canvas(Which is my image itself). I get different results every time.

I want to show 3 texts vertically in center, 3 texts vertically at left and 1 logo at right. I want the watermarks in such way that. if user captures the image from camera or browse through gallery. The texts and logo(watermarks) should be remain of same size and clearly visible, irrespective of the image size or pixel density.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this. I tried Bitmap and Canvas but I am getting different text sizes and blurred text and everything different on different images.

In the below images, here is my problem.

1.Image which was clicked from camera but I used it from browse images

[image: Image which was clicked from camera but I used it from browse images]

2.Image which was selected form Capture Image button

[image: Image which was selected form Capture Image button]

3.random low quality image from gallery

[image]

Here is the code

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(uri)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(200, 100) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                           //this is the required bitmap
                            pikedPhoto = resource.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pikedPhoto);
                            Paint paintCenter = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
                            paintCenter.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                            paintCenter.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // Text Color
                            paintCenter.setColor(Color.RED);
                            //float size = convertDpToPx(context, 25);
                            //paintCenter.setTextSize(size); //Text Size
                            paintCenter.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                            float textY= pikedPhoto.getHeight();
                            float textX= pikedPhoto.getWidth()/2;
                            String text1 = "Centre Text";
                            canvas.drawText(text1,textX,textY,paintCenter);
                            canvas.drawText(text1,textX,textY-10,paintCenter);
                            canvas.drawText(text1,textX,textY-20,paintCenter);


                            String text2 = "Left Text";
                            Paint paintLeft = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
                            paintLeft.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                            paintLeft.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // Text Color
                            paintLeft.setColor(Color.RED);
                            //float sizeLeft = convertDpToPx(context, 25);
                            //paintLeft.setTextSize(sizeLeft); //Text Size
                            paintLeft.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
                            float textYL= pikedPhoto.getHeight();
                            canvas.drawText(text2,0,textYL,paintLeft);
                            canvas.drawText(text2,0,textYL-10,paintLeft);
                            canvas.drawText(text2,0,textYL-20,paintLeft);
                            // in this case, center.x and center.y represent the coordinates of the center of the rectangle in which the text is being placed

                            //canvas.drawBitmap(logo, (pikedPhoto.getWidth()) / 4, 250, new Paint());
                            img.setImageBitmap(pikedPhoto);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: kindly add your attempt code

Comment: I have added the code. @RishabhDhawan

Comment: I tried your code and it is displaying same TextSize for different `Bitmap` sizes. Only issue is that as you are using hard-coded values to draw `text` on `canvas`, so your `texts` might overlap.

Comment: But it is not clear and text size is increasing and decreasing for different bitmap. Is there any way that it show clear and precise and same size of text for any size of bitmaps. Iike an standard watermark. Please help if you can @RishabhDhawan

Comment: this is what I am getting using your code  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0zpmb29x9pjr7m/Screen%20Shot%202020-01-16%20at%2010.59.28%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes if you choose differnt pics from your gallery, Like camera images, whats app images. You will see cahnges in text.

Comment: Yes if you choose differnt pics from your gallery, Like camera images, whats app images. You will see cahnges in text. I want clean and consisting text on every image. @RishabhDhawan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206096/discussion-between-rishabh-dhawan-and-noman-khanbhai).